# Google's VisionAPI example FaceTracker Camera permission

Tags: android, android-camera, google-vision

I'm trying to run [Google Vision FaceTracker](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker) but I have an error on one line of code in `CameraSourcePreview`.

**This is the error** - 
Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with `checkPermission`) or explicitly handle a potential `SecurityException`

And this is the function-

```
private void startIfReady() throws IOException {
    if (mStartRequested && mSurfaceAvailable) {

        mCameraSource.start(mSurfaceView.getHolder()); //Error

        //...other code

        mStartRequested = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Have a look at what permissions FaceTracker needs and then request them by doing int permission = checkPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE); (My example is for file writing, yours will probably be for something else). The check permission method looks like this         int permissionResult = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission);

Comment: Thanks! Fixed the issue, but the app when I run it, just gives me a partially black screen :(

Comment: Have you also checked CAMERA permission ?

Comment: Yes, I have. I'm also allowing it when I start the app.

Comment: Can I add it as the answer?.. Are there any errors for the black screen? Its really weird

Comment: I guess you could. No errors. Here's a question I posted - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43534783/google-vision-facetracker-shows-a-black-screen

Answer (score 0):

**It does seem that you are not getting the correct permissions that FaceTracker needs. For your needs just add the facetracker permissions into the below implementation and interface.**

In our app we added an interface with a callback which handles all our permissions for us :

```
public interface PermissionAndPackageAvailabilityChecker {

    void checkCameraPermission(final PermissionResult callback);

    void checkFileIoPermission(final PermissionResult callback);

    interface PermissionResult {
        void hasPermission();

        void noPermission();
    }
}
```

The implementation is pretty simple :

```
public class DefaultPermissionAndPackage implements PermissionAndPackageAvailabilityChecker {

    private final Context mContext;

    @Inject
    public DefaultPermissionAndPackage(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void checkCameraPermission(final PermissionResult callback) {
        int cameraPermission = checkPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        if (checkHasPermission(cameraPermission)) {
            callback.hasPermission();
        } else {
            callback.noPermission();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void checkFileIoPermission(PermissionResult callback) {
        // Check if we have write permission
        int permission = checkPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (checkHasPermission(permission)) {
            callback.hasPermission();
        } else {
            callback.noPermission();
        }
    }

    private int getTargetSdk(int defaultVersion) {
        int targetSdkVersion = defaultVersion;
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = mContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(mContext.getPackageName(), 0);
            targetSdkVersion = packageInfo.applicationInfo.targetSdkVersion;

        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ignored) {
            //Should not happen . . . I hope
        }
        return targetSdkVersion;
    }

    private int checkPermission(final Context context, final String permission) {
        int permissionResult = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission);
        // this can probably be simplified but explains the logic around permissions nicely.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1
                && getTargetSdk(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) <= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            permissionResult = PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(context, permission);
            //Will check marshmallow here in the future
        }
        return permissionResult;
    }

    private boolean checkHasPermission(int permissionToCheck) {
        return permissionToCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }
}
```