# Google Vision FaceTracker shows a black screen

Tags: android, android-camera, google-vision

Can someone try [Google VisionAPI FaceTracker](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker) and see if it works?

Here's the [official page](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/face-tracker-tutorial).

All I get when I try running it is a black screen (after fixing [one error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43532713/googles-visionapi-example-facetracker-camera-permission)). I don't get any errors in the logs either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample works for me. Of particular note: you should not need to modify the samples to make them work, they should just work.

As such, I also just ran the Face tracking sample as follows:

- `git clone https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision`
- (Install Android Studio)
- Import `android-vision/visionSamples/FaceTracker` into Android Studio
- Click the Android Studio things that install SDK 24 / build tools 24
- From the `android-vision/visionSamples/FaceTracker` folder `./gradlew assemble`
- Create a `Google API` virtual android device with Nexus 5X, setting advanced to a camera when you create the device
- Start your device
- `adb install -r ./app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk`
- Open up app, accept permission, turn your camera sideways

App looks like this:
[image: Demo of app running]

The following could be helpful in diagnosing your issue:

- Can you share the output from `adb logcat`?
- What Android version is the device you're testing the sample on?
- How are you resolving when encountering the "check permission" error?
- What SDK / build tools are you building with (the sample is 0.24)?

Googley Eyes was a little trickier from the emulator because it uses the front camera.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was importing the entire project (Android Vision) from Github, and for some reason it was giving me weird errors, so I just copied all the files one by one, and that gave me the permission error that I had to fix. I just tried what you did and it works perfectly :)